# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: odbc, sqlcmd

Trying to use `sqlcmd` from `mssql-tools` package (loosly following the docs here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-RHEL-6-or-Centos-7) and seeing error

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

even though I believe that both DSN and driver are specified (see below)

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ # trying to connect to DB via DSN (-S option)
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q "select count(*) from MYTABLE" -D -S "MyMSSQLServer" -U "myuser" -P "mypass" -d mydb -W -h-1 -k
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Data source name not found and no default driver specified.
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ # checking odbc config files
[airflow@airflowetl ~]# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ cat /etc/odbc.ini 
[MyMSSQLServer]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description=My MS SQL Server
Trace=No
Server=172.18.1.23

[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini 

[airflow@airflowetl ~]$ ls -lha /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.2.1 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0M Sep 26 06:19 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.2.1
```

Notice that `/etc/odbcinst.ini` is blank when (I think) it should corespond to Driver entries in the `odbc.ini` file. Should I just fill this in manually? Why does it not auto-fill in this case (as it has done on other machines where I have set up odbc)?

Not much experience with ODBC setup, so not sure what to make of this error. Anyone with more experience have any fuirther debugging tips or know how to fix?

Comment: Manually filled in /etc/odbcinst.ini based on the odbc* files on a previous machine where had set this up seems to have fixed the problem. Still not sure why the odbcinst.ini file was not autofilling though. See serverfault.com/a/622088/456930.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the driver? Please have a look this link and follow the steps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Regards
xavy

Comment: Yes. See the bottom of the code block in the post. Manually filled in /etc/odbcinst.ini based on the odbc* files on a previous machine where had set this up seems to have fixed the problem. Still not sure why the odbcinst.ini file was not autofilling though.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running voltdb on docker try this command to access sqlcmd command line:

"docker exec -it [containerId] sqlcmd"

example: "docker exec -it e526d476e6996585d7802dd301813ddd2f0e1b6ef9d0dcfeb65fc8e95aeedb89 sqlcmd"